# assumptions to compute mahalanobis distance

Tags: assumptions, distance, mahalanobis

Which are the assumptions to compute the Mahalanobis distance between two groups? Do all the variables of the two groups be normal distributed?

Comment: Mahalanobis distance itself does not require normality. But what is M.d. "between two groups"? Please define it. I know only two forms of M.d. - between two points of a data clud, and between a point and a centroid of some data cloud.

Comment: I am meaning the distance between two multivariate distributions of data collected by two groups.

Comment: Well, Mahalanobis distance is computed from mean vectors and covariance matrix, so implicitly one is assuming that those are adequate descriptors.